how do I delete unwanted checkpoint on Hyper-V
I am currently running a failover Cluster Manager on Hyper-V. I am getting this error on my backup on a virtual machine. 'VMname' failed to take a checkpoint. (Virtual machine ID A9CC8FC3-B861-4805-9C94-953EC05D4FF2) Cannot take checkpoint for 'VMname' because the maximum limit of 50 checkpoints has been reached. Delete unwanted checkpoints and try again. (Virtual machine ID A9CC8FC3-B861-4805-9C94-953EC05D4FF2)'). Error code: '32768'.
Retrying snapshot creation attempt (Failed to create production checkpoint.)"
When trying to delete the Checkpoints I can't because of the following error "The operation failed because the file was mot found"
When Trying to delete the Checkpoint Subtree this is the error I get "Cannot delete checkpoint subtree containing a recovery checkpoint"
I tried Deleting them Manually it failed.
I tried deleting them using PowerShell still fails with the error "Object not found"

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
